# Put CSRF into Headers in Spring 4.0.3 + Spring Security 3.2.3 + Thymeleaf 2.1.2

Tags: spring, security, csrf, thymeleaf

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <meta name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <!-- default header name is X-CSRF-TOKEN -->
    <meta name="_csrf_header" th:content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
    <title>Fileupload Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<p th:text="${msg}"></p>

<form action="#" th:action="@{/fileUpload}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="myFile"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I get the error HTTP 403:

> Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'

CSRF is working if I use this line instead:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/fileUpload} + '?' + ${_csrf.parameterName} + '=' + ${_csrf.token}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

But how can I achieve working CSRF if I use headers?

Answer (score 26):

After fighting with this issue for some time, I finally figured out why the code in the [official Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-include-csrf-token-ajax) doesn't work... Notice the following:

```
<meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}" />
<meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}" />
```

This is documentation with JSP in mind! Since we are using Thymeleaf, what you need to do is to use `th:content` instead of `content`:

```
<meta name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}"/>
<meta name="_csrf_header" th:content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
```

Now it works!

Answer (score 8):

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"><head>
<meta name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}"/>
<!-- default header name is X-CSRF-TOKEN -->
<meta name="_csrf_header" th:content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
```

and

```
var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
    var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
    $(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
    });

$.ajax({
url: url,
method: 'DELETE',
success: function(result) {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable('remove', {
        field: 'id',
        values: [row.id]
    });
},
    error:function(result) {
    console.log(result);
}
```

});

Solved a problem with jquery ajax request delete .I use Spring Boot , Security and bootstrap -table .

Answer (score 3):

Personally using same configuration as you (Thymleaf, Spring MVC, Spring Sec) i only was able to utilise meta csrf when uploading via ajax and direct inserts into action URL if submitting in standard fashion.
So different types of forms used:

e.g.

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/fileUpload} + '?' + ${_csrf.parameterName} + '=' + ${_csrf.token}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

for Standard submition

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/fileUpload}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

with following javascript:

```
var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
        var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
        $(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
        });
```

to submit via Ajax/jQuery.

Based on my recent research there doesn't seem to be a clean integration between the two and requires slight modifications to make code work.

Comment: I try a lot solution and see a lot document like add "th:name=_csrf.parameterName"  but only this works for me ,anybody knows why?

Comment: th:action="@{/fileUpload} + '?' + ${_csrf.parameterName} + '=' + ${_csrf.token}"